# How can I optimize this function?

Tags: php

I created a function for generating and saving multiple image sizes when a user uploads an image via a web form. I was wondering, how can I better optimize my code (reduce the number of lines while still being easily readable)

`save_image($_FILES['image'], $_GET['member_id'], 250, 300, large) //usage example`

The Function

```
function save_image($file, $id, $sizex, $sizey, $pre){
$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
if ($image){
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
    if (($extension == "jpg") || ($extension == "jpeg")){
        $size = getimagesize($tmpName);
        $max_x = 180;
        $max_y = 300;
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
        $imagex = imagesx($img);
        $imagey = imagesy($img);
        $dim = max($imagex/$max_x, $imagey/$max_y);
        $nx = $imagex/$dim;
        $ny = $imagey/$dim;
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);
        imagecopyresampled($image, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nx, $ny, $imagex, $imagey);
        imagejpeg($image, '../images/uploads/'.$id.'-large.jpg');
        //Make the thumb
        $size = getimagesize($tmpName);
        $max_x = 120;
        $max_y = 230;
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
        $imagex = imagesx($img);
        $imagey = imagesy($img);
        $dim = max($imagex/$max_x, $imagey/$max_y);
        $nx = $imagex/$dim;
        $ny = $imagey/$dim;
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);
        imagecopyresampled($image, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nx, $ny, $imagex, $imagey);
        imagejpeg($image, '../images/uploads/'.$id.'-med.jpg');
        $size = getimagesize($tmpName);
        $max_x = 60;
        $max_y = 115;
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
        $imagex = imagesx($img);
        $imagey = imagesy($img);
        $dim = max($imagex/$max_x, $imagey/$max_y);
        $nx = $imagex/$dim;
        $ny = $imagey/$dim;
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);
        imagecopyresampled($image, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nx, $ny, $imagex, $imagey);
        imagejpeg($image, '../images/uploads/'.$id.'-thumb.jpg');
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}else{
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Wow, whitespace is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I noticed you create a variable and it has not been used.

`$size = getimagesize($tmpName);`

So why call a function and assign its value when it is not being used.

Secondly to get the width and height you don't have to do

`$imagex = imagesx($img);`

`$imagey = imagesy($img);`

So I would suggest you replace the 3 lines mentioned in this code with a single one

`list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($tmpName);`

Finally instead of duplicating the code create a function with parameters passed and call the function as it is shown in the comments above.

Also noticed that you send "large" i.e image size as the parameter then why are you running through the thumb and med cases. Would suggest use switch cases like change the save function to

function save_image($_FILES['image'], $_GET['member_id'], 250, 300, $type = "large")

and then use a switch on $type.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 times almost the same code

```
    $size = getimagesize($tmpName);
    $max_x = 60;
    $max_y = 115;
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
    $imagex = imagesx($img);
    $imagey = imagesy($img);
    $dim = max($imagex/$max_x, $imagey/$max_y);
    $nx = $imagex/$dim;
    $ny = $imagey/$dim;
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);
    imagecopyresampled($image, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nx, $ny, $imagex, $imagey);
    imagejpeg($image, '../images/uploads/'.$id.'-thumb.jpg');
```

You should easily be able to make a function for that, that's a good start.

Comment: In addition, you should be using your parameters ... the second and third lines $image = $_FILES [ 'image' ] [ 'name' ], why are you doing that?  You are passing it in as a parameter.  if ( $image ) should be if ( isset ( $file [ 'name' ] ) ) instead because it will do a soft read rather than a hard one if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your code is redundant.

You could make a little function :

```
function repetitiveFunctionForPicture($image, $max_x, $max_y,$tmpName, $file){
    $size = getimagesize($tmpName);
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
    $imagex = imagesx($img);
    $imagey = imagesy($img);
    $dim = max($imagex/$max_x, $imagey/$max_y);
    $nx = $imagex/$dim;
    $ny = $imagey/$dim;
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);
    imagecopyresampled($image, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nx, $ny, $imagex, $imagey);
    imagejpeg($image, '../images/uploads/'.$id.'-large.jpg');
}
```

which can be called like this :

```
repetitiveFunctionForPicture($image, 180, 300,$tmpName, $file);
```